# How to take this after unload in vue project

Tags: vue.js

Sorry guys I'm not a native English speaker, I have a problem I want to send data when the page is closed but I can't get this, does anyone have a solution?
`navigator.sendBeacon(url, this.data);`

Comment: You may use ``beforeunload`` event. ```window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
        navigator.sendBeacon(url, this.data);
      });```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, but I still can't get the display undefined